# Calculating the norm of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

So I've been given the matrix A

A = [1 2; 3 1]
and the question is:

If v is an error vector with ||v|| = 0.01, give an upper bound on ||A^30v||.

||A^30v|| = ||A^30|| * ||v||, correct?

I used the norm function (norm(A^30)), and it gave me a number, but I don't think it's correct:

Basically my question boils down to: Does norm(A^30) return the norm of matrix A^30, because according to matlab index, it returns the largest singular value of A^30. IF norm(A^30) is not what I'm supposed to use, what should I use?

Answer (score 2):

The norm of a matrix and the norm of a vector are different things, and they have different definitions.

`norm(A^30)` will return $\|A^{30}\|_2$, or more generally `norm(B)` returns the largest singular value of $B$.

However, note that $Bv$ is a matrix, so `norm(B*v)` will return $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (Bv)_i^2}$.

Since $\|B\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} (B^*B)}$, then $\|B\|\|v\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} (B^*B)}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2}$.

One should not expect that these two quantities are the same in general.

---

What you need to know is that since $\|v\| = 0.01$, then $v$ lies somewhere on a circle around the origin. $A^{30}$ is a linear transformation on any vector in this circle. So, you simply need to figure out how $A^{30}$ transforms the circle, and find the farthest point.

Comment: Lots of people in my year are doing norm(A30), then multiplying it by V, that's not correct is it? I ended up with 5.67e14, and they ended up with 1.38e14.

Comment: The formula $\|A^{30}\|_2 = \max \frac{\|A^{30} v\|_2}{\|v\|_2}$ may be useful.

Comment: What does the 2 beside the A30 mean? Is that the norm of the 2nd column vectors?

Comment: It means it's the matrix 2-norm. There are many matrix norms. Before you proceed further on this problem, you should brush up on the concept of matrix and vector norms a bit more.

Comment: Thing being, we haven't learned about norms of matrices yet, but somehow we've been assigned an assignment for it : /. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you haven't been taught about computing matrix norms, then don't solve the problem by computing matrix norms. $\|A^{30}v\|$ is not a matrix. It is a vector. Compute its norm by examining the properties of the linear transformation of $v$ by $A^{30}$.

Answer (score 1):

norm(A*v) $\le$ norm(A)*norm(v).  You do not in general get equality.